# Breakdown Git version number

Tags: mac, git, github

Fairly new to Git. I recently updated it on my Mac. I upgraded using these 4 commands:

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
$ cd git
$ make prefix=/usr/local all
$ sudo make prefix=/usr/local install

$ git --version
git version 1.7.3.2.164.g6f10c
```

my old version of Git was simply: 1.7.1.x

Do I have a pre-release build? If so how can I use git, itself, to checkout the most recent *stable* build? `git branch -a` gets me:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/html
  remotes/origin/maint
  remotes/origin/man
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/next
  remotes/origin/pu
  remotes/origin/todo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this breaks down as follows:

The version of git you're running is one that has had 164 commits since version  1.7.3.2. The exact git revision number begins with  the prefix `g6f10c`  (these 6 digits should be enough to uniquely identify the commit if you need to refer to that revision in particular).

You can see released versions by running `git tag` and you can get version 1.7.3.2 *exactly* by running `git checkout v1.7.3.2`.

Comment: thank you! this sounds like it'll work. sorry for Git unfamiliarity. So after `git checkout v1.7.3.2` i then checked the local branches with `git branch` and I see the `master` and `* (no branch)`. i was expecting to see `master` and `* 1.7.3.2`. say i walk away from this project for a few weeks and come back. how can i tell what version is currently in my local repository?

Comment: @Meltemi tags are different from branches. Branches are intended to follow concurrent directions of development, so git remembers that you're on a particular branch, and allows you to commit new changes to the branch. A tag is a snapshot of a particular version at a particular point in time, so the running `git branch` will say you're on `(no branch)`. To know what version is currently in your repository, `git checkout master`, and run `git describe`. It will give you a version number that breaks down like I described here.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with `git describe`. i just ran it on my local repository and it came back with `v1.7.3.2` which is what i was expecting. Thank you!  So, last question: is `* (no branch)` normal? or do I want to somehow name it? or should I just build and install and then delete this (no branch)? seems weird, to me, to have active branch name (no branch) lingering around on my machine...  I really don't want to keep dev builds on my machine. just want to understand a workflow for using git to get its own source and then build/install it...

Comment: `(no branch)` is normal when you've checked out a tag. It means you're not on a branch and you can't commit. To get a better idea what's going on, look at [Understanding Git Conceptually](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/). After you've read about heads, there's only one detail to add: a branch is a head that moves frequently, and a tag is a head that doesn't (ordinarily) move.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly reasonable to consider the tip of git.git’s *master* stable.

From [Documentation/howto/maintain-git.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/howto/maintain-git.txt;h=d527b307707c676e82a08f18cb9fdd7d3abcb228;hb=HEAD#l68):

> The tip of 'master' is meant to be more stable than any tagged releases, and the users are encouraged to follow it.

Before a new feature is ever merged into *master*, it is reviewed on the mailing list and “cooked”  (often for several weeks) in the *pu* and *next* branches that the developers regularly test and use.

Git’s version numbers work like this:

```
      o----- major release: 1.7
     / o---- feature release: 1.7.3
    / / o--- maintenance release: 1.7.3.2
   / / /
1.7.3.2
```

Major releases often contain incompatible changes. Feature releases introduce new features. Maintenance releases contain bugfixes.

*master* is almost literally a merge of the latest maintenance release and the current accumulated features for the next feature release.

The output of `git --version` is based on the output of [*git describe*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html) on the commit that was used to build the binary (see [GIT-VERSION-GEN](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=GIT-VERSION-GEN;h=d441d88d6fbd6d98bb617e5cf5d2bd7704f86a45;hb=HEAD)).

The output from *git describe* adds extra information to better “nail down” the specific version when you are based on a commit that is not explicitly tagged.

```
         o------------- most recent reachable tag: 1.7.3.2
        /          o--- 'g' + abbreviated object name of built commit: 6f10c
       /          /
1.7.3.2.164.g6f10c
           \
            o---------- number of commits in built commit "on top" of tag: 164
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, 1.7.3.2 is the latest stable version available via http://git-scm.com/  What makes you question if you have the latest?

Comment: Because he got his version of git from git's git repository where they do active development on the `master` branch.

Comment: @Ken: git.git’s *master* is hardly “active development”. Changes to git.git are reviewed on the mailing list, “cooked” in the *pu* branch, if they are sane they graduate to the *next* branch and they gradually are merged down into *master*. *master* also gets all the bugfixes from *maint* right away. [“The tip of *master* is meant to be more stable than any tagged releases”](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/howto/maintain-git.txt;h=d527b307707c676e82a08f18cb9fdd7d3abcb228;hb=HEAD#l68).